# How to get list of Handlers connected to Android Looper?

Tags: android

How can I get the list of Handler objects attached to particular Looper (i.e. Thread) ?
I mean both system defined handler (managing activity views events in case of UI Thread) and user defined handlers, if any.

Comment: There's no way to do this (that I can see) with the current APIs. What would be the purpose of doing so anyway?

Comment: @Karakuri Just to know how this thread is "overloaded" with handlers - both developer defined and system defined ones. Is there exactly one or more of them ? I am just curious how to elegantly collect this information at runtime.